# MTG Deadlock Trap

Tags: magic-the-gathering

It is my turn and I have [Bristling Hydra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBristling%20Hydra%5d) on the battlefield and [Blossoming Defense](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlossoming%20Defense%5d) in my hand. During the Beginning of Combat
my opponent uses [Deadlock Trap](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeadlock%20Trap%5d)'s ability on my Bristling Hydra. 
Can I then play [Blossoming Defense](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlossoming%20Defense%5d) or activate the Hydra's ability to fizzle the Deadlock Trap? And does it matter which I use, or would either one work?

Comment: What makes you think this might not happen? Are you wondering about what happens when the target of an ability is illegal, or what order do things resolve on the stack, or something different entirely?

Comment: Also the last chance your opponent has to tap your hydra to prevent it from attacking is during the Beginning of Combat step, once it has been declared as an attacker the Trap will not do anything to the Hydra.

Comment: As an addenda......could I bypass the blossoming defense and just activate the Bristling Hydra's ability to make the Deadlock fizzle?

Comment: If you are wondering about that it should get added to the question.

Comment: Thanks Diego.  I guess the real question may be:  my opponent activates the Deadlock trap's ability, can I then activate the Hydra's ability to fizzle the Trap.  I am thinking I can.

Comment: I made some edits to the question, if it doesn't align with the question you meant to ask feel free to roll the edit back

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this works like you expect it to. You can activate the hydra's ability, or cast the Blossoming Defense in response to the Trap's ability, it doesn't matter which one you use since they both grant hexproof.

When a spell or ability attempts to resolve one of the things it does is make sure it still has legal targets. In this case your Hydra would have hexproof which makes it an illegal target for your opponents spells. Since the ability no longer has any legal targets it will be countered and not have any effect.

> **608.2b** If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal. [...] The spell or ability is countered if all its targets, for every instance of the word “target,” are now illegal. If the spell or ability is not countered, it will resolve normally. [...]